# How safe is a roof just over the front door?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, cleaning

I see a lot of leaves and branches in my roof valleys (4 of them) and want to go on the roof to clean that up.

Example of roof valley with built-up detritus (the bottom part I just cleaned up):

[image]

I do think that any heavy rain is an issue with such build up. It's going to work as a dam and the water will go under the shingles.

So, to properly clean the entire valley, I want to climb on the roof. I don't have an issue with that per se, but I'm wondering about the porch-like area by the front door. The following picture shows a white beam in the center of the picture. I think that the roof from that beam up is as usual and the part before that is weaker (and in case of my house, that part seems rather wide). As far as I know, once away from the weaker part, it is safer to walk on the roof. Am I right?

[image]

---

To give an extend of the amount of leaves & branches, here is a pile of what I already removed from the front door two roof valleys. My shoes are 12W. The height of that pile is about 2× my shoes in the center.

[image]

Comment: Going in that corner might be okay, instead of the centre.  Without knowing how it is built, can only assume it will hold weight, but it is not my neck on the line.  Places with a snow load should be built stronger than places without snow, but roofers had to be up there.

Comment: @crip659 Yeah, and in the Sacramento valley we don't get snow too often... That said, that was my first thought, actually... to climb on the side rather than over the front door.